# SpringBoot : @DependsOnDatabaseInitialization throwing Cicular Dependecy Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my existing code base when i am migrating from Springboot2.7.2 to Springboot3.2.0 and java8 to java17 .Spring-boot application failing with the error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   webSecurityConfig (field private <PackageName>.WebSecurityConfig.securityService)
      ↓
   securityService (field private <PackageName>.SecurityService.authenticationService)
      ↓
   authenticationService (field private <PackageName>.AuthenticationService.systemParameterService)
      ↓
   systemInitialService defined in file [C:\<PackageName>\SystemInitialService.class]
      ↓
   userRepository1 defined in <PackageName>.UserRepository1 defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on WsApplication
      ↓
   jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory
┌─────┐
|  dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]
└─────┘

 
Action:

Despite circular references being allowed, the dependency cycle between beans could not be broken. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle.
```

If i removed the `@DependsOnDatabaseInitialization` annotation ,this issue will not appear again.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

  private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, dialectMapping.get(dbType));
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE, 20);
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_JDBC_FATCH_SIZE, 20);
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_GLOBALLY_QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS, false);
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_ENABLE_LAZY_LOAD_NO_TRANS, true);
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_CACHE_USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, false);
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_CACHE_USE_QUERY_CACHE, false);
        properties.put(JAVAX_PERSISTENCE_SHARED_CACHE_MODE, SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);

        if ((dbType).equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Database.PSQL)) {
            dbSchema = StringUtils.isBlank(dbSchema) ? dbUsername : dbSchema;
            properties.put(HIBERNATE_DEFAULT_SCHEMA, dbSchema);
        }
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOnDatabaseInitialization
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(driverMapping.get(dbType));
        ds.setUrl(dbUrl);
        ds.setUsername(dbUsername);
        ds.setPassword(decryptPassword(dbPassword));
        ds.setInitialSize(initialSize);
        ds.setMaxActive(maxActive);
        ds.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
        ds.setMinIdle(minIdle);
        ds.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);
        ds.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(minEvictableIdleTimeMillis);
        ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(timeBetweenEvicRunsMillis);
        ds.setTestOnBorrow(testOnBorrow);
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(validationQuery)){
            ds.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
        }else if (dbType.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.Database.ORACLE)){
            ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
        } else {
            ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        }
        ds.setValidationInterval(validationInterval);

        ds.setRemoveAbandoned(removeAbandoned);
        ds.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(removeAbandonedTimeOut);
        ds.setMaxAge(maxAge);
        ds.setLogValidationErrors(logValidationErrors);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.comptel");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        entityManagerFactory.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ALL);
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOnDatabaseInitialization
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

then it will start throwing

> defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on WsApplication: Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while
> setting bean property 'entityManager' Caused by:
> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider
> does not implement the requested interface
> jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

While i am using jakarta*. libraries in place of javax*.

Comment: You need the datasource to initialze it. YOu now, indirectly, have a dependency of the datasource on the datasource.

Comment: Do you mean i have to remove `@DependsOnDatabaseInitialization`

Comment: Yes, from the datasource. The `dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer` needs the `DataSource` but the `DataSource` now depends on the `dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer`, thus a cycle. But why do you have this configuraiton at all if you are using Spring Boot? Spring Boot will automatically configure the datasource and entitymanager for you already? Also you shouldn't be using a `validationQuery` JDBC4+ have better means which are automatically used.

Comment: Thanks for your. Its existing code and working fine with the Springboot2.7..2 ,now with Latest Springboot release its started failing. Any example you can share how datasource can be configure in latest release.

Comment: You shouldn't have that code but just use `spring.datasource` properties. Remove that annotation from the method will make it work. Next I would work on removing code you don't actually need that Spring Boot already provides through auto configuration.

Comment: Removing the `@DependsOnDatabaseInitialization` now throwing this exception `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument` and in details `Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`

Comment: You removed it from where? And as stated I would remove those beans and create the proper configuration in your `application.properties` or `yaml`. Next to that the error you now have feels like you are also mixing incompatible versions of Hiberate with Spring (the fact that you have all those beans makes me wonder what you have in your dependencies...).

Comment: I am using `Springboot3.2.0,spring-orm-6.1.1,jakarata-persitance-api-3.1.0,hibernate-core-6.3.1`